# How return value with Asynchronous Http Client loopj

Tags: android, asynchronous

I currently using loopj Android Asynchronous Http Client (http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) It is just a general question about this library if someone has already used this libreary.

This code is on the sample page i gave just above. With this, we can receive data from TwitterAPI in onSuccess like tweetText. But how is it possible to use the value of tweetText outside function onSuccess ?

I tried a lot of things like global variable or change type on onSuccess but i didn't found a solution. I just want the value of tweetText in another class or function...

```
class TwitterRestClientUsage {
    public void getPublicTimeline() throws JSONException {
        TwitterRestClient.get("statuses/public_timeline.json", null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                // If the response is JSONObject instead of expected JSONArray
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray timeline) {
                // Pull out the first event on the public timeline
                JSONObject firstEvent = timeline.get(0);
                String tweetText = firstEvent.getString("text");

                // Do something with the response
                System.out.println(tweetText);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thank per advance.
PokeR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ,

1. Define static variable in a separate class

   ```
   public class MyConstant
   {
     public static String tweetText;
   }
   ```

Then , within your onSuccess, you can assign the value as follows

```
            @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray timeline) {
            // Pull out the first event on the public timeline
            JSONObject firstEvent = timeline.get(0);
            MyConstant.tweetText = firstEvent.getString("text");

            // Do something with the response
            System.out.println(MyConstant.tweetText);
        }
```

2. Or else Use Android SharedPreferences, you my find lots of tutorials here